# Play Framework Redirect all traffic

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm slowly converting a REST API from Rails to Scala. I've got some methods working with play, but others have to fall back to the Rails server.

I want all requests to go through Play, but if they aren't implemented yet to redirect. Specifically if URL requested is play-app.com/api/v1/.* then it should be redirected to rails-app.com/api/v1/.*, with URL and all params in tact. I've tried this route:

```
GET /api/v1/*path
```

But now I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: Are you using some sort of frontend server? (By the way, that's the usual approach to running Play.) If so, handle the redirection via the frontend server.

Comment: That was my first thought, but right now it's running on Heroku so I don't think that will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your route is

```
GET   /api/v1/*path                  controllers.Api.v1(path: String)
```

Then your controller function would look something like this:

```
object Api extends Controller { request =>
    val queryString: String = if(request.rawQueryString.nonEmpty) "?" + request.rawQueryString else ""

    def v1(path: String) = Action {
         TemporaryRedirect("rails-app.com/api/v1/" + path + queryString )
    }
}
```

Comment: There are post requests too, if I copy the route and change GET to POST will it still work? And pass through the post body?

Comment: That's dependent on whether the browser is willing to replay the request. It might be quicker to actually just try that, as you already have the other server. I've added an extra line for handling query parameters as well.